# Swing and SWT event auto logger

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, swt, rcp

Our desktop application has a lot of use cases. And pretty often is very difficult to reproduce defect and specify all steps how to reproduce it.

Is it possible to create something like Interceptor for all Swing and SWT events and log them to console without put log.info in each actionListener() or view activator, on menu contributor etc.?

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you can do something like this.

```
public class MyEventQueue extends EventQueue {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger( MyEventQueue.class.getName() );
    @Override
    protected void dispatchEvent( AWTEvent newEvent )
    {
        try {
             logger.info("New Event start: "+ newEvent.toString() );
             super.dispatchEvent( newEvent );
        } catch( RuntimeException  e ) {
            //log uncatch exceptions in edt
            logger.error(e.getCause(),e);            
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "someDescriptiveMessage");
        }
    }
}
```

And you can use a helper method to set it before application starts.

```
 public static void captureUncaughtExceptionInEvent(){            
            EventQueue queue = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemEventQueue();
            queue.push(new MyEventQueue());
 }
```

Comment: This will log all events